# Fetch data from firebase database and componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, fetch

I have a problem fetching data from firebase with componentDidMount().
Fetching the data working fine but the problem is when it comes to lifecycle method. I console.log out the fetched data.[image: console.log]

it fetched data when the component renders and after it fetched, the data become undefined and my render method appeared and disappeared in 0.001sec.
Do I need to store the props data into the state in order to not to disappear
Thank you for the help!

#### Action

```
export const fetchUserAddressbook = () => {
    const { currentUser } = auth;
    return dispatch => {
     database
      .ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/shippingAddress`)
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_SUCCESS,
          payload: snapshot.val()
          });
        });
      };
    };
```

#### class

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchUserAddressbook();
}


 render(){
 return
 (
  <div>{this.renderAddressCard(this.props.shippingAddressBook)}</div>
 )


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
   shippingAddressBook: state.user.shippingAddressBook
  };
 }
```

#### renderMethod

```
renderAddressCard(shippingAddressBook) {
    return _.map(shippingAddressBook, (value, uid) => {
      return (
        <Card header={value.companyName} />

      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: you are missing a closing brace on your mapStateToProps.

Comment: @LeoFarmer Thank you, I edited the post. but there is the closing brace in actual codes.

Comment: You should also check that you have data before attempting to render. e.g. `<div>{this.props.shippingAddressBook && this.renderAddressCard(this.props.shippingAddressBook)}</div>`

Comment: I have a feeling you are dispatching `FETCH_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_SUCCESS` somewhere else and overwriting your data. If you use Redux devtools, look at what the user state looks like after it has fetched. Or put a break point in the reducer and see if it's being dispatched twice.

Comment: @Max Thank you so much for the answer. I totally forgot about Redux dev tool, and I found the error on other reducers and it works find now :) Thank you!!!!!